# What database can i use for a wallpaper app?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm developing a wallpaper app but I dont exactly know which database I can use to store the images (SQLite or MySQL) .Can you please help me if you have some experience in this domain ?

Comment: Hi Massadi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is quite broad, and difficult to answer. Could you [edit] your question to give more details - for example, do you know what kind of data you want to store in the database? And how much data you think you will be storing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a DB to directly store the images as BLOBs, they can get very very bulky.

Instead use any of the above DB and save the Links to your images with your images actually being stored elsewhere.

Good places to store images would be Dropbox, drive etc..

Also there are good CDN providers which allow you to save images and also provide image manipulation as well as caching features.
i use cloudinary...

Also i will suggest you to use Picasso/Fresco/Universal Image Loader for actually handling the images in your app... They will deal with caching/memory and other issues and save you a lot of trouble

The DB is really upto you.. hope this helps

Comment: Terrible question, but good answer.